# How to enable kubectl in a EKS cluster which do have permission to assume the role through it was created?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-eks, user-roles

I need to access EKS Cluster through EC2 instance sitting in same VPC in which EKS Cluster is created, and we do not have secret key available for that role?

I have tried created the roles with all admin permission and assign that role to EC2 instances and try to access it through system manager but I could not able to authenticate the EKS cluster. By default I am using EC2privateDNSconfig role which is there in AWSAuth.

Can I create a user and assign a role and add it to AWSAuthConfig and able to access the EKS cluster?

Comment: This doc page describes how to add additional roles/users to the AWS Auth config map: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/add-user-role.html. Have you tried that?

Comment: I have tried that, But I am not able to login to cluster so could I overwrite a AWSAuth file from outside of cluster or anyway to access it through EC2 System manager?

Comment: I don't know how you would change the AWS auth config map from the outside. The config map is a K8s construct and you need to change it "from within the context of the K8s cluster" using the account that has created the cluster (which is not listed in the config map BUT it's by default a cluster admin - the only one by default).

Comment: As per accessing the instances, you can configure the instances with a key to allow SSHing into them ([see here for example](https://eksctl.io/usage/eks-managed-nodes/)). I haven't explored SSM to do that but I guess you could use it as well to get a shell. However having access to EC2 instances and having access to the cluster as an admin are two different orthogonal things.